# Cron Job command fix

Tags: cron

below command for cron job is not working

```
20 18 * * * wget -O /dev/null 2>&1 http://www.rolsonscommercial.com/cronjobs/sms/autosms.php.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving an absolute path to wget (/usr/local/bin/wget on my system).  You can use

```
$type wget
$which wget
$whereis wget
```

to figure this out

Also answer, what operating system? what version of cron?  Is this a user crontab or system crontab - they have different formats.

Also, when do you want the cron job to run? "not working" is useless information.  Answer "what do you expect?", "what is happening", "what are you doing?"

Comment: As a note, my wget is in `/usr/bin/wget` so OP better run `which wget` to know the exact location of his wget binary.

Comment: @Nelson - good point - I expanded on this in my answer.

Comment: The desired time to execute the script is already there in the command to understand. I expect the script to run at the specified timing and send sms to the users. But nothing is happening.

Comment: Right, but if you are putting this in /etc/crontab it has a different format than a user crontab (it adds the username as a field). Please answer everything I asked you.